# SQL Server Stored Procedure Dynamic where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

If `orderid is not null` then in SQL query I want to append

```
and SODtl.OrderID = @OrderID.
```

I have use 2 select queries. I want only one select statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SOReg_Select]
            @OrderID int=null,
            @From date =null,
            @To date=null
AS
begin
    if  @OrderID is null
    begin
        SELECT     
            SODtl.OrderID, SODtl.OrderLine, Products.ProductName, 
            SODtl.Style, SODtl.Width, SODtl.Size, Color.Color, 
            SODtl.Quantity, Uom.Name, SODtl.Rate, SODtl.Amount, 
            SODtl.BalQty, SODtl.Remark, SOHdr.OrderDate, 
            Customers.ContactName, SOHdr.RefNo, SOHdr.RefDate, 
            SOHdr.Payment, SOHdr.Terms, SOHdr.Remarks
        FROM         
            Products 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN
            SODtl 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Uom ON SODtl.UomID = Uom.UomID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Color ON SODtl.ColorID = Color.ColorID ON Products.ProductID = SODtl.ProductID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            Customers 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN
            SOHdr ON Customers.CustomerID = SOHdr.CustomerID ON SODtl.OrderID = SOHdr.OrderID
        WHERE
            OrderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To                             
  end          
  else
  begin
      SELECT     
          SODtl.OrderID, SODtl.OrderLine, Products.ProductName, 
          SODtl.Style, SODtl.Width, SODtl.Size, Color.Color, 
          SODtl.Quantity, Uom.Name, SODtl.Rate, SODtl.Amount, 
          SODtl.BalQty, SODtl.Remark, SOHdr.OrderDate, 
          Customers.ContactName, SOHdr.RefNo, SOHdr.RefDate, 
          SOHdr.Payment, SOHdr.Terms, SOHdr.Remarks
      FROM         
          Products 
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          SODtl 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
          Uom ON SODtl.UomID = Uom.UomID 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
          Color ON SODtl.ColorID = Color.ColorID ON Products.ProductID = SODtl.ProductID 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
          Customers 
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN
          SOHdr ON Customers.CustomerID = SOHdr.CustomerID ON SODtl.OrderID = SOHdr.OrderID
      WHERE
          OrderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To   
          AND SODtl.OrderID = @OrderID
    end
end
```

This is what I have done. I want the query to be simplified and don't want the repetition of select statement

Comment: Mixing LEFT JOINS with RIGHT JOINS like that... crazy! Btw, which table does the column OrderDate belong to?

Comment: Use the COALESCE function for 'If not null then get the value' part of the query. it's something like OrderID  = Coalesce(@OrderID , OrderID ) or something. I don't remember the exact syntax but read about Coalesce function and you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT SODtl.OrderID,
       SODtl.OrderLine,
       Products.ProductName,
       SODtl.Style,
       SODtl.Width,
       SODtl.Size,
       Color.Color,
       SODtl.Quantity,
       Uom.Name,
       SODtl.Rate,
       SODtl.Amount,
       SODtl.BalQty,
       SODtl.Remark,
       SOHdr.OrderDate,
       Customers.ContactName,
       SOHdr.RefNo,
       SOHdr.RefDate,
       SOHdr.Payment,
       SOHdr.Terms,
       SOHdr.Remarks
FROM Products
RIGHT OUTER JOIN SODtl
LEFT OUTER JOIN Uom ON SODtl.UomID = Uom.UomID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Color ON SODtl.ColorID = Color.ColorID ON Products.ProductID = SODtl.ProductID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers
RIGHT OUTER JOIN SOHdr ON Customers.CustomerID = SOHdr.CustomerID ON SODtl.OrderID = SOHdr.OrderID
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To
  AND ((SODtl.OrderID=@OrderID)
       OR (@OrderID IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT 
  /* Columns */
FROM Products 
  /* Joins */
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To
  AND SODtl.OrderID = ISNULL(@OrderID, SODtl.OrderID);
```

And you can remove from your code `IF THEN ELSE`.

Optionaly you can change `ISNULL` to `COALESCE` or `CASE WHEN` or `OR` statement to generate at least 4 possible solutions.